# Move data between two Amazon RDS databases in different AWS accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a database in Amazon RDS, it's in production.

I have another DB in the same region as production but another AWS account and want to fill in the DB with the production DB data.

How can I achieve this fast? Any articles?

I tried to create a snapshot and then share it with the other account but the db version isn't allowing it. I cant export the data on s3 because the engine mode isn't supported. I cant query each table and export to CSV because they are large data.

Any recommendations? Thank you

Comment: what SQL server is it?  Postgers, mysql, mssql .. ?

Comment: Are you wanting to copy ALL data from the source database to the destination database, or only a subset of tables/data? Is there other data in the destination database that needs to be preserved, or are you okay to launch a totally new destination database with the data (which is how snapshots work)? Are you able to upgrade the databases so they re operating on the same version?

Comment: FYI questions asking for articles and other recommendations are off-topic here. Also, this isn’t really a programming question, and doesn’t really fit here.